# Lazy-loading only unloaded-chunk diffs with webpack

Tags: webpack

I am using `require.ensure` to create chunks, which are lazily loaded based on route in an Angular SPA. I am not using any special lazy-loading plugin for Angular, just ui-router's resolve.

Chunk #2 requires the contents of #1. For example:

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
   require('shop/shop');         // Creates chunk 1
}, 'Shop');

require.ensure([], function(require) {
   require('signup/signup');      // Creates chunk 2
}, 'Signup');

// signup/signup.js
define([
  '_auth.scss',
  'shop/shop'                    // Chunk 2 depends on chunk 1
], function() { });
```

My output from webpack looks roughly like this:

> Asset -------- Chunk
>
> app.js ------- 0
>
> 1.Shop.js  ---------- 1
>
> 2.Signup.js ---------- 1,2

If I navigate from {1,2} -> {1}, I make no requests, because {1} was satisfied by {1,2}. But if I go {1} -> {1,2}, I receive all of {1,2} rather than just a chunk containing {2}.

Is there a way that I can receive only the "unloaded chunk diff" from a chunk with Webpack?

I have tried using the CommonsChunkPlugin in this manner:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/extra-async-chunk

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
   name: 'main',
   async: true
})
```

But if I use 'main', then somehow I end up with a gigantic final bundle/chunk which is larger than even my entrypoint which contains most of the vendor code.

If this is not supported by Webpack currently, would it be reasonable to assume that one could write a plugin that generates files for the possible valid permutations of "unloaded chunks", and then loads the right one at runtime?

Thanks for any insight!!

My webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 100;

var alias = {
  json3: 'json3/lib/json3',
  es5shim: 'es5-shim/es5-shim',
  angular: 'angular/angular',
  lodash: 'lodash/lodash',
  angularRoute: 'angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router',
  angularAnimate: 'angular-animate/angular-animate',
  moment: 'moment/moment',
  'angular-moment': 'angular-moment/angular-moment',
  'angular-cookies':  'angular-cookies/angular-cookies',
  'angular-encode-uri': 'angular-encode-uri/dist/angular-encode-uri',
  'angulartics-gtm': __dirname + '/app/vendor/angulartics/src/angulartics-gtm',
  angulartics: __dirname + '/app/vendor/angulartics/src/angulartics'
};

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app/scripts',
  entry: {
    app: 'bootstrap.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/scripts',
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/scripts/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      _: 'lodash'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /moment[\/\\]locale$/,
      /be|de\-at|de|en\-gb|es|fr|it|nl|pl|pt|pt\-br|ru|sv/
    )
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /[\/]angular\.js$/, loader: 'exports?angular' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html', include: __dirname + '/app/scripts' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass', include: __dirname + '/app/styles/sass' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
      { test: /angular\-moment/, loader: 'imports?define=>false&angular&moment'},
      {
        test: /images\/.*\.svg$/i,
        loaders: [
            'file?name=[path][name].[ext]',
            'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.html', '.scss', '.css', '.svg'],
    root: [ __dirname + '/app' ],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'vendor',
      'scripts',
      'styles/sass',
      'icons'
    ],
    alias: alias
  },
  noParse: Object.keys(alias),
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map'
};
```

Comment: Have you tried `name: 'app'` instead of `name: 'main'` because your entry point is named `app`?

Comment: @TobiasK. Yep, I still get the same chunks generated. I suppose the desired outcome is that {1}, {2}, and {1,2} are all generated as separate chunks. Is that an expected behavior already? (Thanks!)

Comment: {1,2} doesn't mean that there are two parts {1} and {2}. It just means this chunk number 2 also contains all modules of chunk number 1 (by luck). Your usecase (loading `2-1.js` instead of `2.js` when `1.js` was already loaded) is not supported. The approach with async extra chunk would (if possible, never tried) result in `1.js` and `2.js` loading in parallel with `2.js` containing only modules that are not in `1.js`.

Comment: @TobiasK. Do you mean "loading `2.js` instead of `1-2.js` when `1.js` was already loaded"? And if this is not possible, do you think it would be feasible [for me] to write a plugin to achieve this? Or would this be out of the scope of webpack's capabilities altogether?

Comment: my sentense was right. `2-1.js` mean `2 minus 1.js`. Maybe it's possible to do it manually with a bit of hacky code. I'll try to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this with webpack automatically, but this is an idea for a manual way:

Totally untested and pretty hacky, but it may solve your problem for this special case.

```
// chunk 1 loading (as before)

require.ensure([], function(require) {
   require('shop/shop');         // Creates chunk 1
}, 'Shop');

// chunk 2 loading:

// check if shop already loaded
if(require.resolveWeak("shop/shop") in __webpack_modules__) { 

  // the first require.ensure maps to chunk 1 but doesn't load anything
  // because it's already loaded
  require.ensure(['shop/shop'], function(require) {
    // the second require.ensure creates a child chunk and the optimization
    // removes all modules which are already in chunk 1
    require.ensure([], function(require) {
      require('signup/signup');      // Creates chunk 3 = 2 minus 1
    }, 'Signup2'); // important: other name (or no name)
  }, 'Shop');

} else {

  // full chunk load
  require.ensure([], function(require) {
    require('signup/signup');      // Creates chunk 2
  }, 'Signup');

}
```

Comment: Very helpful, and also helped me stumble onto the "API in modules" documentation. I will see where this leads me and post my findings. Thank you!